# Issue with form validation in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the latest version of codeigniter but I have an issue. Whenever I submit the data with the necessary details, no database insert occur, `form_validation->run() == FALSE` always return false like there was an issue with the submitted data.

This is my code:

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('user_model'); //database inserter

}
public function submit_join(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'is_unique[students.username]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'valid_email|is_unique[students.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Mobile No.', 'numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'min_length[4]|max_length[20]|matches[confirm_pass]|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_pass', 'Confirm Password', 'matches[password]|md5');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // fails
       $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There was an error when verifying your details!</div>');
        $this->load->view('join');
    }

     else
    {
        //insert the user registration details into database
        $data = array(
            'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
            'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
            'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone')
        );

     //Insert to database function
   }

}
```

Comment: load form_validation library then you used validation

Comment: check whether input name and the name given in your validation set_rule are same

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('session','form_validation');  add autoload.php in config folder

Comment: Just tip I see your using md5 for password on form_rules. Don't use MD5 any more not secure use the php http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and to verify use callback http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: add `echo validation_errors();` inside your if condition to see what the error is passing @dealwap

Comment: @FairyDancer i got: `The Password field cannot exceed 20 characters in length.` even when the password is not up to 20 characters.

Comment: then remove max_length in your validation @dealwap because you encrypting as md5 so it take more than 20 length... Once you removed it start saving your data... Hope it will solve your problem... If not tell me im happy to help you with..

Comment: @FairyDancer, after removing the max_length I got `The Password field does not match the confirm_pass field.` as error message even when i am very sure the password field and confirm isthe same.

Comment: @dealwap. Try to remove validation once at a time and check focus one by one. On your Password rules, try to remove `matches[confirm_pass]|md5` as it is already appearing on conf_pass.

Comment: We will continue this in chat. Join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146504/codeigniter

Comment: @FairyDancer, the code you gave in the chat works but I am not able to chat due to low `reputation.`

Comment: ok. Is your problem solved @dealwap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you load the form validation library? It's not in your constructor or function so this may solve the issue.

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('user_model'); //database inserter

    //Add this library
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```

Comment: i have that in my autoload.php

Comment: Try removing MD5 from both password and confirm_pass. Also, try using only one matches. For example, remove matches [confirm_pass] from the password rules.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check that all the fields name are the same as you set in validation rule , than Check that `is_unique[students.email]` is a valid field in your connected database is your student database contain email field if everything is ok then try to load the form validation library correctly in the controller ,

remove the md5 in in confirm password rule .
Set form validation error to the form in the view like

```
<?php echo form_error('name');?>
```

to spot the error